# How to change order of string value in column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

how to use a scala udf to change the order of a string

```
   root
    |-- Loc: string (nullable = true)
    +----------------+
    |             Loc|
    +----------------+
    |8106f510000dc502|
    +----------------+
8106f510000dc502 to 08f150000dc50261
```

i want to convert it like this order [3,1,5,7,6,(8-16),4,2]

Comment: can you add more data for example ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *appears* like a Scala coding assignment and has *almost* nothing to do with Spark.

I'd do the following:

```
// the dataset
val loc = Seq("8106f510000dc502").toDF("Loc")

// the udf for decoding loc
def mydecode(codes: Seq[Int]) = udf { s: String =>
  codes.map(pos => s.charAt(pos)).mkString
}

val codes = Seq(3,1,5,7,6,4,2)
val decoded = loc.withColumn("decoded", mydecode(codes)($"loc"))
scala> decoded.show
+----------------+-------+
|             Loc|decoded|
+----------------+-------+
|8106f510000dc502|61501f0|
+----------------+-------+
```

I'm leaving the range in the `codes` array, i.e. `(8-16)` as your home exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to turn from `100z200` to `200z100` on column `Loc` then defining `udf` function as below should be sufficient (assuming that you have `z` in middle of every string in the column)

```
def reverseReplace = udf((str: String) => {
  val index = str.indexOf("z")
  str.substring(index+1, str.length)+str.substring(index, index+1)+str.substring(0, index)
})
```

You can call the `udf` function as

```
val m4=msc3.select("Loc").withColumn("Info", reverseReplace($"Loc"))
m4.show(false)
```

You will have following output

```
+-------+-------+
|Loc    |Info   |
+-------+-------+
|100z200|200z100|
|30z400 |400z30 |
|600z10 |10z600 |
+-------+-------+
```

**Edited**

According to what I understand from your updated question that you want your final result in `[3,1,5,7,6,(8-16),4,2]` order, following can be your `udf` function

```
def reverseReplace = udf((str: String) => {
  val len = str.length
  val index = 16 > len match {case true => len case false => 16}
  var finalStr = ""
  if(len > 2)
    finalStr += str.substring(3-1,3)
  if(len > 0)
    finalStr += str.substring(1-1,1)
  if(len > 4)
    finalStr += str.substring(5-1,5)
  if(len > 6)
    finalStr += str.substring(7-1,7)
  if(len > 5)
    finalStr += str.substring(6-1,6)
  if(len > 7)
    finalStr += str.substring(8-1, index)
  if(len > 3)
    finalStr += str.substring(4-1,4)
  if(len > 1)
    finalStr += str.substring(2-1,2)
  if(finalStr == "")
    finalStr = str
  finalStr
})
```

You can call this `udf` function as stated above

Comment: thank you from your answer; but i want to play with the order of the chars not reverse it. so sorry for the bad example i take.example  `125fh569x to 52fh55x69` put the third char first and ect.... thank you for your time

Comment: If my edit of your question is correct and if `125fh569x` is to be turned to `51h659xf2` then see my updated answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using regular expression and an UDF that can be assigned a separator (in this case "z"):

```
def flip(sep: String) = udf(
  (s: String) => {
    val pattern = s"""(.*?)${sep}(.*)""".r
    s match {
      case pattern(a, b) => b + sep + a
    }
  }
)

val df = Seq( ("100z200") ).toDF("Loc")

val dfFlipped = df.withColumn("Flipped", flip("z")($"Loc"))

dfFlipped.show
+-------+-------+
|    Loc|Flipped|
+-------+-------+
|100z200|200z100|
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: thank you from your answer but i'm trying to get a general udf when i can play with all chars and mix the order ; like this example 10ze864 to ze81046